# Baire category of tall ideals

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, infinite-combinatorics

> **Problem.** Is it consistent with ZFC that $\mathfrak t=\omega_1$ and each $\omega_1$-generated tall $P$-ideal is of the second Baire category?

(Asked 01.10.2016 by David Chodounsky at page [20](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=1&page=20) of [Volume 1](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=1) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka)).

Prize: *A bottle of Becherovka.*

Comment: But Becherovka is not very tasty. :(

Comment: In small quantities it is a medicin :)

Comment: Some might argue that I'm not that kind of sick, though! ;)

Comment: I have added ([tag:infinite-combinatorics]) - feel free to revert the edit if you think the tag does not fit, but to me small uncountable cardinals seem rather close to my understanding of infinitary combinatorics. (I was also considering adding ([tag:decriptive-set-theory]) but it is probably not ideal fit here.